# Unable to Send Register Id(GCM) with the web service on Login Acticity

Tags: android, web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android and this is first time I am doing push notification and I am getting Registration Id from cloud server in my Log **System.out.println("Registration ID:  " + registrationId);** **GCMIntentService Class** but I am not able to send it to backend as a param with URL on my Login Screen. I am posting my code here. please help me guys.

CommonUtilities.java

```
public final class CommonUtilities {
/**
 * Base URL 
 */
public static final String SERVER_URL ="";

/**
 * Google API project id registered to use GCM.
 */


// date 16 april 2015
public static final String SENDER_ID = "332948388069";
```

//  API_Key=AIzaSyCBpVn9J2TWxPZDqyilCssUh5dbphQQtWE

```
/**API_Key=AIzaSyDsAQ_ynBJNPCOstGcDjAwRReDWF5uYsc0
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
public static final String TAG = "Sample";

/**
 * Intent used to display a message in the screen.
 */
public static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.xxxxxxxx.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

/**
 * Intent's extra that contains the message to be displayed.
 */
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

/**
 * Notifies UI to display a message.
 * <p>
 * This method is defined in the common helper because it's used both by the
 * UI and the background service.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            application's context.
 * @param message
 *            message to be displayed.
 */
public static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
 }
 }
```

GCMIntentService.java

```
import static com.xxxxxx.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import static com.xxxxxx.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
            errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = "Testing";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home_Screen.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}

}
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edit_email, edit_password;
String email, password;
Button btn_submit;
ProgressDialog dialog;
TextView tv_count, attempt;
String value, url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.php?caseid=5",
        forget_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.php?caseid=7";
Parser parser = new Parser();
TextView txt_signup, forgot_password;
String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
int count = 3;
String devicetype = "android",deviceid,regid;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    attempt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attempt);
    attempt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tv_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
    tv_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    forgot_password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
    edit_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
    edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
    btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    txt_signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_signup);
    txt_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, SignUp.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    deviceid = Secure.getString(Login.this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true)
    {
        checkNotNull(CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");
        checkNotNull(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
  //Register Device on GCM Server
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
        regid = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        if (regid.equals("")) {
            // Automatically registers application on startup.
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);

        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
            // if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // // Skips registration.
            // } else {
            // // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, regid);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }
            };

            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            // }
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          new LoginTask().execute();
        });
    }

    private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(
                getString(R.string.error_config, name));
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            }
        };


public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", deviceid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devicetype",devicetype));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", regid));
        System.out.println("email: "+email+" deviceid: "+deviceid+" devicetype: "+devicetype+" regisid: "+regid);

        JSONObject json = parser.getJSONFromUrl(url, nameValuePairs);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        try {
            int result = json.getInt("udata");

            if (result == 1) {
                SaveSharedPreference.setUserEmail(Login.this, email);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home_Screen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
            if (result == 2) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email id or password not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                tv_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                attempt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //  tv_count.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                count--;
                tv_count.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                if (count == 0) {
                    btn_submit.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btn_submit.setEnabled(false);
                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception", "" + e.toString());

        }


    }
  }
```

ServerUtilities.java

```
import static com.xxxxxx.CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL;
import static com.xxxxxx.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;

public class ServerUtilities {
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
private static final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;
private static final Random random = new Random();

/**
 * Register this account/device pair within the server.
 *
 */
static void register(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.e("registering(regId = ", "" + regId + ")");
    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);

    long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
    // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
    // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
    // times.
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        Log.d("Attempt #","" + i + " to register");
        try {
            displayMessage(context, context.getString(
                    R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));
            post(serverUrl, params);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
            // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
            // (like HTTP error code 503).
            Log.e("Failed to register" ,""+ i + ":" + e);
            if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Log.d("Sleeping for ","" + backoff + " ms before retry");
                Thread.sleep(backoff);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                Log.d("Thread interrupted:","");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
            // increase backoff exponentially
            backoff *= 2;
        }
    }
    String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
            MAX_ATTEMPTS);
    CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
  }

  /**
   * Unregister this account/device pair within the server.
   */
  static void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i("unregistering(regId = ","" + regId + ")");
    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/unregister";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    try {
        post(serverUrl, params);
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // At this point the device is unregistered from GCM, but still
        // registered in the server.
        // We could try to unregister again, but it is not necessary:
        // if the server tries to send a message to the device, it will get
        // a "NotRegistered" error message and should unregister the device.
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregister_error,
                e.getMessage());
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
      }
   }

/**
 * Issue a POST request to the server.
 *
 * @param endpoint POST address.
 * @param params request parameters.
 *
 * @throws IOException propagated from POST.
 */

 private static void post(String endpoint, String params)throws IOException {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        connection_respones_String = new WebResponseClass();
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        InputStream inputStream;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(defaultHttpClient.getParams(), 180000);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endpoint);
        HttpEntity entity;

        List<NameValuePair> params_post = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params_post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", params));
        try {
            entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params_post);
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // this should never happen.
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }

        // StringEntity se = new StringEntity(params_post);
        // System.out.println("StringEntityyyyyyyyyy"+se);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // connection_respones_String =
            // convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            connection_respones_String.setStrData(convertInputStreamToString(inputStream));
            connection_respones_String.setResponse(httpResponse);
  //if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
 //Jsonloginset set = Utill
//.getAuthenticationFromJson(connection_respones_String
 //.getStrData());
 //connection_respones_String.setData(set);
  //}
            System.out.println("result>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+connection_respones_String.getStrData());
        }
        // else
        // connection_respones_String = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("qqqqqqqqqqq"
            + connection_respones_String.getStrData());



}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;
    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you send messages to your server properly? Have you tried it without the gcmRegId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem at your Login because your are getting and sending the Reg_Id on the same screen so quickly it needs some some to get generated from the cloud server sometimes it not able to get and your param remains null. Try one thing get it on Splash Screen and save it to your SharedPreference and then send it on your Dashboard Screen.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you enabled gcm in google play services in your project

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but my GCM API is enable and I already mention that I am getting id from cloud server in my Log but unable to send it with by web service.